# Generate and format current date and time

Tags: javascript, datetime

How to do the following in JavaScript?:

```
$curr_time_start = new DateTime();
$timeStart = date_format($curr_time_start, 'Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like

```
var d = new Date();
alert(
    d.getYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDay() + ' ' + 
    d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes());
```

[javascript Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the plugin from Matt Kruse -

http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/

Answer (score 1):

Natively it's not possible to do such a thing with Javascript.

There are many ways to accomplish that using frameworks or specific libraries.

For example, with [MooTools](http://mootools.net) you can do this:

```
var timeStart = new Date().format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
```

You can test this with this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeE9q/).

The syntax for the format is almost the same, but for the `%M` instead of `i` for the minutes, and because all the placeholders are prefixed by `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library.

Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy and fast. Datejs has passed all trials and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t just parse strings, it slices them cleanly in two.